# Variable out of scope error with (I assume) the correct scope declaration - C#

Tags: c#, async-await, scope

The use-case is a GUI with a checkbox, where I only want to run the compliance check (an external python script) if the checkbox is marked. If the compliance check runs, I want to save the output string from the processing.

Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
Task<string> comp_python;
if (compliance) // compliance is t/f based on whether the checkbox is marked
{
    string cmd = "some python command";
    comp_python = runCompAsync(cmd);
}

// some processing

if (compliance)
{
    string comp_res = await comp_python; // out of scope error here on comp_python
}
```

I am getting an out of scope error on the comp_python Task object in the second conditional. I have tried removing all of the processing between these two blocks and my scope is still wrong. Any ideas?

If this can be accomplished another way with reworked code, I can accept an alternative solution as well.

Comment: What is a "out of scope" error? Please post the *exact* error message you get

Comment: not declared in current scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of reachability and definite assignment do not know that `compliance` is the same value at both `if` statements. Thus, the compiler considers it possible that it is `false` at the first `if`, and `true` at the second `if`. `comp_python` will never have been assigned on that path; it was *declared* but it was never *definitely assigned* per the definite assignment rules. (A local variable is **not** null / default if it's left unassigned, it is a compiler error if a possibly-unassigned local is accessed.)

One way to fix this is to split out your intervening code into another method (or a local method if this is the only method that uses it), allowing you to have the declaration, assignment, and usage of the local all be in one block.

```
if (compliance) // compliance is t/f based on whether the checkbox is marked
{
    string cmd = "some python command";
    Task<string> comp_python = runCompAsync(cmd);

    someProcessing();

    string comp_res = await comp_python;
}
else
{
    someProcessing();
}
```

Language specification reference: [reachability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#122-end-points-and-reachability) and [definite assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#94-definite-assignment).

Comment: Okay this makes sense. Python is way more friendly. Your solution makes sense, but I am going to see if I can another way to implement this. The initial assignment doesn't have to be null, but Im not sure how to structure the async code around that. Maybe I can try calling the async method every time and check the checkbox value within